# How to click on the element with text as Contact using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium to grab all support page of some site.On one particular page i have one error . 
Here the code of the page :

```
<a href="?a=support" class="">
<span><b></b> Contact</span>
<b></b> Contact
</a>
```

I'm trying with many try / except condition to find a support page.

```
try:
    print ("FINDING SUPPORT ...")
    driver_hyip.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='support']").click()
    driver_hyip.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
except:
try:
    print ("NOT FINDING SUPPORT, TRYING ANOTHER WAY")
    driver_hyip.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='?a=support']").click()
except:
    print ("NOT FINDING SUPPORT, TRYING TO FIND CONTACT")
    driver_hyip.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='contact']").click()
```

I expected my code find the page, but I got :

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href*='contact']"}
```

PS : Do you know if there is some other way to try multiple path in selenium ? Because here i'm doing lot of try / except in my code.

Comment: you can use `OR` in xpath to club multiple conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Contact** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='support']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'support')]/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```